# How to use nested FOR loops in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, nested-loops

I have some code in which I want to use a `FOR` loop to handle a set of files. 
As part of handling a file there's a `FOR /F` loop that reads it and appends data to an other file based on the file name.

In order to be able to set the output file name I have delayed variable expansion set on.

This is what the code should look like as I originally intended it to be:

```dos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (DataFolder\*.Ext) do (
    set POI=%%~f
    set POI=!JbPOI:DataFolder\=!
    set POI=!JbPOI:.Ext=!
    for /f  "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in ("%%~f") do (
        set CX=%%a
        set CY=%%b
        set FN=%%c
        echo !FN!,9,!CX!,!CY! >> "DataFolder\!POI!.tmp"
    )
)
endlocal
```

This code doesn't work because variable `%%a`, `%%b` and `%%c` never receive a value, `%%a` always has the same value as `%%f`.

I have read some articles about this issue but couldn't extract a solution from them that worked.

I have tried several things, none worked so far...

- added a dummy outer loop to create variable `%%a` through `%%j` explicitly
- inner `FOR` loop taken out and made it a subroutine
- inner `FOR` loop taken out and made it a separate batch file

Can anybody please tell me how this can - or must - be solved?

Comment: I'd say the easiest solution is to install Python and write a small Python script for it. Or really any other language besides MS batch.

Comment: do you want to read the content of file `%%~f` or to use its name as a string.Because now you're using it as a string.

Comment: File %%f is to be read ... If it is treated as a string this way: that makes sense explaining why %%a has always tha same value as %%f. I am going to do some more testing ...

Comment: The usebackq option did all the work! The inner loop was treating the quoted file name as a string, instead of a file to read. Thanks a lot, npocmaka!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (DataFolder\*.Ext) do (
    set POI=%%~f
    set POI=!JbPOI:DataFolder\=!
    set POI=!JbPOI:.Ext=!
    for /f  "useback tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in ("%%~f") do (
        set CX=%%a
        set CY=%%b
        set FN=%%c
        echo !FN!,9,!CX!,!CY! >> "DataFolder\!POI!.tmp"
    )
)
endlocal
```

I'm not sure if you want to read the file `"%%~f"` , but I think this is what you need.

Comment: shouldn't `useback` be `usebackq`?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but for the posted code i don't see the need for delayed expansion. All the needed data is being directly retrieved from the `for` replaceable parameters

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (DataFolder\*.Ext) do (
  (
    for /f  "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ("%%~f") do echo(%%c,9,%%a,%%b
  ) > "DataFolder\%%~nf.tmp"
)
endlocal
```

If the real code includes something not posted, maybe the answer from npocmaka will better fit in the problem.

Comment: As you can see, part ouf the ouput file name is derived from the %%f file name, but not completely ... some characters are stripped off.

Comment: @JaapBregman, yes, the path and the extension. `%%~nf` will return only the file name with no path and no extension.