# How to find m3u playlist filesize in batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10, batch-processing

I'm trying to find the filesize of m3u playlist files in a directory. I don't know the correct syntax for batch script, so the below code might not run properly.

I need help regarding this script.

```bat
FOR /f %f in ('dir /b') DO {
  SET %filesize% = 0
  FOR /F %i in (%f) DO {
   If %i~1,1% equ ":" AND %i~2,1% equ "\" (%filesize% = %filesize% + %~z1)
  }
 echo %f [%filesize%] & echo. > PlaylistsList.txt
}
```

1. First line scans the base directory for m3u files,
2. Second line sets a variable filesize to 0, so that it doesn't keep getting added in each loop.
3. The third line takes each m3u playlist file as a text file input for processing in another loop.
4. Fourth line checks if the filepath format is in `"C:\music\"` format, by comparing the `2nd` and `3rd` character via `:` & `\`. Then filesize is added for each file found in the m3u playlist file.
5. Finally the filename is echoed along with the filesize.

Hence the output in the PlaylistsList.txt:

> Rock.m3u [900 mb]
>
> Electronic.m3u [500 mb]
>
> Acoustic.m3u [150 mb]

Comment: you want to get the sum of the sizes of the files in the playlist?

Comment: Yes! I'm trying to get the total filesize of the music playlist.

Comment: 1. Do not guess the syntax, learn it! enter `for /?` in a command prompt window to learn how it works; do the same for `set` and `if`. 2. There are no keywords like `AND` and `OR`; however, you could do something like `if a EQU 1 if b EQU 2 ...` to create a logical `AND`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I'll try and learn the syntax from the command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, variable names in for loop in batch files must be preceded with 2 `%`s. So insert more percent signs to your variables. Second, put your blocks inside parentheses `()`, not `{}`

---

Another problem is your `set` command. Variable name in set isn't surrounded by percent sign, and the assigned value must be right after the equal symbol, or your variable's real value will include the preceding spaces. The correct way is like this: `SET filesize=0` or `SET "filesize=0"`

You're also adding the filesize of the first parameter again and again (notice `z1` there instead of `zi`

```bat
%filesize% = %filesize% + %~z1
```

You must get the size of the files in the list using `%~zi` and add it to the sum. However you can't do math directly like above. Use `set /a` instead

```bat
set /a filesize += %%~zi
```

---

And you're reading the m3u file content incorrectly. To [read a line from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/155932/995714) use this way

```bat
for /F "tokens=*" %%L in (%%f) do [command]
```

I don't understand your 4th this line. You want to check if the line begins in `C:\music\` but you instead check if the second character is `:` and the 3rd one is `\`. There are several problems with this:

- `IF` doesn't support multiple conditions like `AND`
- You can't substring a variable in for loop, because it isn't surrounded by percent signs like normal variables.

To substring, assign the value to a normal variable first: `set line=%%L`. To check for both conditions there are several workarounds [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8438511/995714), but your case is just checking for a single string so you don't need to check for separate characters. Use `if "!line:~1,2!"==":\"` if you want the behavior above, or `if /i "!line:~0,2!"=="C:\music\"` to check for the folder you mentioned, use `/i` for case insensitive check. Variables in the for loop must be surrounded with `!!` to make it expand at runtime. Remember to use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning.

At the end you don't need to `& echo.` because echo always put a newline after printing. But you must use `>>` to append the output file, or it'll erase the old content every time you redirect `echo`.

---

Now to make filesize you need to do the math yourself because filesize is just a numerical value. Note that there's no unit for data size called `mb`. Divide by 1024 if you want MiB (MB in Windows term) and divide by 1000 to get MB.

So the script should looks like this

```bat
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%f in ('dir /b') DO (
    set filesize=0
    for /F "tokens=*" %%L in (%%f) do (
        set line=%%L
        if "!line:~1,2!"==":\" set /a filesize += %%~zL
    )
)
set /a filesize /= 1024
echo %%f [%filesize% MB] >> PlaylistsList.txt
```

Bonus: If a rounded file size result is desired, use

```bat
set divisor=1024
set /a filesize = (%filesize% + %divisor%/2) / %divisor%
```

---

## Edit:

To accommodate for long file names, the second for loops should be used with `usebackq` like this

```bat
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%L in ('%%f') do (
```

Another way is calling another function to get file size

```bat
set line=%%L
CALL :FileSize "%%L"
if "!line:~1,2!"==":\" set /a filesize += %%~zL

:FileSize
SET filesize=%~z1
```

One important note is that variables used in `set` are 32-bit signed int, so **it won't work if the total size exceeds 2GB**.

Comment: Thanks Luu! A slight problem, I'm getting an appended output of `%f [0 MB]` in my txt file, and via `pause` I found out that since my m3u filenames have spaces, therefore the script is not able to find the m3u files! Error: `Cannot find the file "Folder"` (while my m3u files might be `Folder 1`.. I tried `set f="f"` before the second for loop, and still the error appears.

Comment: ah you need `set f="%%f"` and then use `%f%` instead

Comment: Well, I didn't understand that. I solved it by adding `"tokens=* delims="` to for loops. Also, another question is that the batch script is not treating the `.m3u` files as text. The filename appears in the echo, but the `%%L` is displayed with only `%L`, m3u filename appears although the file is not opened by the script. The `%%f` in the second for loop is being treated as a string, not a file.

Comment: Hi! I finally got the script working... I'm about to post it as an answer, please correct your code as per that script, so that I can select your answer as the answer to this question! Thanks!

Comment: Well, [useback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090735/how-to-use-nested-for-loops-in-batch-files) solved the issue of filename being treated as string via the question page linked in this comment.

Comment: it should be `usebackq` although I don't know why useback also works

Answer (score 1):

Corrected from Luu's Answer!

```bat
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('dir *.m3u /b') DO (
    set filesize=0
    REM set var1="%%f"
    REM echo %var1%
    for /f "useback tokens=* delims=" %%L in ("%%~f") do (
        set line=%%L
        if "!line:~1,2!"==":\" set /a filesize += %%~zL
    )
    REM set /a filesize /= 1024
    echo %%f [!filesize! MB] >> PlaylistsList.txt
)
pause
```

Comment: no need to put filesize in `!!` because you aren't changing it's value in a loop anyway

Comment: Well, the filesize wasn't showing up in the text size, so I read your explanation about how variables could be enclosed between double `!!` marks.

Comment: I forgot you're putting size inside the outside loop